# Removing duplicates from a comma-separated string and assigning them to a row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table consisting of three columns.

One of the columns consists of a comma-separated list of building numbers:

| Id | PropertyNumber | BuildingNumbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4315 | 11594 | 1,5,6,10,10,11 |
| 3434 | 44379 | 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 |

I'm trying to write an UPDATE SQL statement, which will remove the duplicates from the BuildingNumbers table, so that my table will look like this:

| Id | PropertyNumber | BuildingNumbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4315 | 11594 | 1,5,6,10,11 |
| 3434 | 44379 | 1,2,3,4 |

How can I achieve this?

I'm using a [SQL Server 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2019) and Microsoft [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) 18.

Comment: You can use `STRING_SPLIT` but a better idea would be to **not** store data this way. If you want to query building numbers they need to be in their own field, in a related table. Trying to store multiple values in a single field violates the most basic design rule and prevents you from efficiently finding eg all the data related to a single building

Comment: It's possible to store data as JSON or XML both in SQL Server and other databases but that's meant to store data that's rarely queried in a "bucket". Even in databases that provide array types or can index JSON columns (eg Oracle and PostgreSQL but not SQL Server or MySQL) querying such fields is slower and more complex than proper tables and fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is a quite complex task due to this bad idea to save data in that way. In the future, you should get rid of this structure.

I guess something like this should work correctly, but maybe you need to do some modifications:

```
WITH split AS
(SELECT id, PropertyNumber,
CAST(split.Value AS INT) AS BuildingNumbers
FROM yourtable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(yourtable.BuildingNumbers,',') split
GROUP BY id, PropertyNumber, CAST(split.Value AS INT)),
updateData AS
(SELECT id, PropertyNumber, STRING_AGG(BuildingNumbers,',') AS BuildingNumbers
FROM split
GROUP BY id, PropertyNumber)
UPDATE y SET y.BuildingNumbers = ud.BuildingNumbers
FROM yourtable y
INNER JOIN updateData ud
ON y.id = ud.id
AND y.PropertyNumber = ud.PropertyNumber;
```

I created a fiddle based on your sample data which shows this should be ok: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RXdkGOIJ)

As you can replicate in the fiddle, the idea is following:

1. Split the comma-separated list of values in the distinct different values per id.
2. Build again a comma-separated list of those distinct values per id.
3. Update the data, replace the previous comma-separated list with the new one.

A last note: This answer focuses on the way how to update your data, not on how to improve your data structure in the future, because this was not your question.

However, I recommend, as already said in the beginning of this answer, to review your structure and save the data in a better form. One option is shown in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74812751/removing-duplicates-from-a-comma-separated-string-and-assigning-them-to-a-row-in/74823155#74823155).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This really solved my problem, especially the dbfiddle link! As for how the database is structured: I agree that it violates basic table structure design. This should never be the approach and I would never design something like this myself.

Comment: What does "Emrebener's answer" refer to? It was added about 30 minutes after [Lilith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74823155), but it could also refer to [Parth M. Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74822013) (there is an even earlier answer, but it was deleted before this answer was posted (thus unlikely)). It is best to include (non-naked) links in case user names change (they can change at any time (which appears to be the case here)).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know user here change their name. Edited my answer and added the link to the answer I mean.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is related to your design. I think you need to rethink your table structure. I will elaborate on Panagiotis Kanavos's reply. You should have a "Buildings" table and a "Properties" table. There will be a column in "Buildings" table for "PropertyID" with which you will specify the relationship for each individual Building. Your tables should look something like this;

**PROPERTIES TABLE;**

| PropertyID | PropertyName |
| --- | --- |
| 4315 | 11594 |
| 3434 | 44379 |

**BUILDINGS TABLE;**

| BuildingNumber | PropertyID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4315 |
| 2 | 3434 |
| 1 | 3434 |
| 4 | 4315 |
| 2 | 4315 |
| 6 | 3434 |

This way, the connection between buildings and properties are managed in a proper way. You *can* set up FK relation between BuildingTable's PropertyID column and PropertyTable's PropertyID column, but you don't exactly have to. It just would be good practice and would reduce chance for errors down the road.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It would be better altogether to avoid data structures like these and make a more sounding data design. However, in many cases, people have to maintain existing data and code or need some ad hoc query for processing poorly exported data. As such, it is often impossible (or unnecessary in case of a one-time import) to immediately redesign the underlying system. I guess that questions like these are for some incidental help for such an ad hoc problem at hand.

Comment: Having said that, I do suspect that the underlying data design of the OP's existing table is poorly designed and needs proper redesign asap. ;)

Comment: @BartHofland You're right. This is poor data design. I would love to restructure this particular table, but in this situation it is old data, that just needs a good amount of maintenance.